# Gerar automaticamente um menu dropdown da minha base de dados

Tags: php

**Código**

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/dbhinc.php';
$sqlc1="SELECT camada1_name, camada1_id from camada1";
$sqlc2="SELECT camada2_name, camada1ref from camada2
inner join camada1 on (camada1.camada1_id)=(camada2.camada1ref)";

$resultc1 = $conn->query($sqlc1);

while($row = $resultc1->fetch_assoc())
{
    $utfEncodedArray = array_map("utf8_encode", $row);

    //  echo '<li><a href=profile.php>',$utfEncodedArray['camada2_name'],'</a></li>';
    echo'  <li>
    <label for="drop-1" class=toggle>',$utfEncodedArray['camada1_name'],'</label>
    <a href="#">',$utfEncodedArray['camada1_name'],'</a>
    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1"/>';
    //  echo'<ul><li><a>',$blyat['camada2_name'],'</a></li></ul></li>';
}
```

O que eu quero e basicamente gerar todas as "camada1" como um botão e  através destes botões fazer um "dropdown" de "camada2", Eu tentei varios código, e não sei o que eu estou fazendo de errado.

**Minha base de dados**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, redija sua pergunta em português.

Comment: E coloque seu código e não a imagem dele.

Comment: Por favor, deixe o titulo em portugues, como já foi dito o idioma do site  é **Português**.